# C# .net Core Exception - change message in the child class

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

*Possible misunderstanding of OOP principles*

I have class of type `Exception`

There I `catch` my custom exceptions, and I want to drop text `ORA-20001:` from messages

My code here and it doesn't work:

```
public class ApiException : Exception {
  public ApiException(string message) : base(message) {
    message = message.Replace("ORA-20001: ", "");
}
```

Code when I get `Exception`:

```
try {
  ToDo(Request);
} catch (ApiException ae) {
  Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
}
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: `base(message.Replace("ORA-20001: ", ""))`

Comment: @vc74 it's work well - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the updated message to the base constructor:

```
public class ApiException : Exception {
    public ApiException(string message) 
      : base(message.Replace("ORA-20001: ", "")) {
}
```